# Highlighting Text using javascript not working

Tags: javascript

I'd like to highlight or change the background color of all p elements to yellow but it won't work.

I would also like my button be a toggle to highlight and highlight the paragraph elements. Is that possible? Help would be appreciated!

```
 <html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="task2.js"></script>
  <style>
  #poem {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: silver;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    width: 30%;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="poem">
<h2> How Many, How Much  </h2>
<h4> by Shel Silverstein </h4>
<p> How many slams in an old screen door? </p>
<p> Depends how loud you shut it.</p>
<p> How many slices in a bread?</p>
<p> Depends how thin you cut it.</p>
<p> How much good inside a day? </p>
<p> Depends how good you live 'em. </p>
<p> How much love inside a friend? </p>
<p> Depends how much you give 'em. </p>
</div>

<button id="yellow">Click to Highlight </button>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my external js file

```
window.onload = function()
{
  document.getElementById("yellow").addEventListener("click", makeYellow);
}

function makeYellow() {
var paragraph = document.getElementsbyTagName("p");
paragraph.style.color ="yellow";
}
```

Comment: I do not understand why you don't call a function onClick. That would solve this.

Comment: I need to have an unobtrusive javascript style

Comment: First off, it's `document.getElementsByTagName` and second, `paragraph` is an `array`. You need to loop through the elements to set a style color.

Comment: can you teach me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`.
I've attached a JSFiddle to see with 2 options - one iterates through the paragraph

```
var paragraph = document.querySelectorAll("p");
    paragraph.forEach(p => {
      p.style.color ="yellow";
    });
```

and the second option simply adds a css class to the parent (#poem) and is obviously the preferred way.

```
var poem = document.querySelector('#poem');
    poem.classList.add('yellow'); // and of course you need to define the `.yellow {color: yellow;}` in your css.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L0dnbj0h/2/

Hope this helps.

Comment: maybe i'm just dumb but it doesn't work when I put it on external js file. it works perfectly on the jsfiddle though

Comment: @KenmourNoble try and put the external js file at the end of the HTML, right before the closing `body` tag

Comment: both don't work for me. I'm trying a new method wherein I'm using the getElementsbyTagName and put it on a loop to get all paragraph lines to be yellow but it doesn't work too

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('some_id').onclick= function() {
        var p = this.parentNode.style;
        p.color = yellow;
    };
</script>
```

Edit: Toggle button

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('some_id').onclick= function() {
            var p = this.parentNode.style;
            if (p.color = yellow) p.color = white;
            else p.color = yellow;
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: will this also work on external javascript? I need to do an unobtrusive style

Comment: @KenmourNoble Yes it will

Comment: As for the 2nd one, I like to change all my paragraphs into color yellow by using the button, right? I would like to use the same button to undo the color changes so it acts like a toggle for highlighting and unhighlighting

Comment: Do your paragraphs have an id? It should look like this
<p id="colorParag"...>
document.getElementById('colorParag').onclick....

Comment: can't I just use getElementsbyTagName so i don't have to use ids on them?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("yellow").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("poem");
    if (x.style.color == "blue") {
        x.style.color == "yellow";
    } else if (x.style.color == "yellow") {
        x.style.color == "blue";
    }
}
```